# If I serve /favicon.ico as image/vnd.microsoft.icon, instead of image/x-icon, will it break on any browsers?

Tags: internet-explorer-6, mime-types, favicon

If I configure Apache to serve `/favicon.ico` as MIME type image/vnd.microsoft.icon, instead of image/x-icon, will it break on any browsers?  Wikipedia's [favicon article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) indicates that image/vnd.microsoft.icon is the "correct" mime type, but that doesn't help if it means some users won't see it.

I need to support IE6+, as well as modern browsers (FF/Chrome/Opera/Safari).

Comment: If you are able to set up a website serving the favicon you could use something like http://browsershots.org to test compatibility with a wide range of browsers. It takes a screenshot of the whole browser window, including the displayed favicon.

Comment: good idea, i'll try that

Comment: There were a few browsers (I think IE6 included) that didn't like `image/vnd.microsoft.icon`, but everything was OK with `image/x-icon`, so I'm going to stick with that for a while.  Thanks for the suggestion.  Sorry I forgot to come back and accept this answer... :-/

Answer (score 5):

Off the top of my head, `image/vnd.microsoft.icon` will work only if the image actually is a real ICO file, while `image/x-icon` is less fussy, and will also work for bitmaps and GIF images. (Non-ICO files with the `.ico` file extension are, I believe, quite common.)

Comment: Yeah, ms (among others) has been known to suggest that procedure -- even in their article about how to add a favicon to your site...

Comment: In general you should not serve any file with a wrong MIME type and expect it to work. The extension, however, is irrelevant. So if you want to serve a PNG or GIF as `favicon.ico`, you should manually configure your server to use the actual type. In Apache this can be done with the `ForceType` directive, or you can set up a 301 redirect to the file you want to use instead.

Answer (score 4):

Google serve /favicon.ico as image/x-icon, and I'd guess they know what they're talking about (or at least, what's compatible).

Comment: I'm guessing this answer is somewhat antiquated, as this is no longer true.

Comment: @Chuck is right. Google no longer links to any icon at www.google.com/ or www.google.com/search. However, www.google.com/favicon.ico exists. However, I bet Google knows what they are doing. According to my server logs, a quick `grep|wc` shows that there have been 4,676 requests for my icon (silhouette.ico), which is specified using the `<link>` tag. However, there have also been 2,897 404 requests for "favicon.ico." After glancing at some of the user agents, I think it is safe to say that most browsers of all types will request /favicon.ico by default. I think Google is leveraging that fact.

Comment: Google also serves invalid HTML …