# Using Stream to display Image *.ico

Tags: c#, asp.net, stream

I want to show image with extension `*.ico` and I use `Stream` to do it. But I have a problem that.

With Extension `*.jpg`, `*.bmp`... Image show ok but `*.ico`, it does not show

Here is my code:

```
 private void OutputStream(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            Stream dataStream = null;

                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    SPFile spFile = web.GetFile(fileName);
                    dataStream = spFile.OpenBinaryStream();
                    this.HandleOutputStream(dataStream);
                });

        }
        catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException exTemp)
        {
            logger.Error("KBStreamPicture::OutputStream", exTemp);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("OutputStream::" + ex);
            logger.Error("KBStreamPicture::OutputStream", ex);
        }
    }
```

and

```
private void HandleOutputStream(Stream dataStream)
    {
        const int bufferSize = 16384; //16KB 

        using (Stream file = dataStream)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                this.Page.Response.Clear();
                this.Page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.Private);
                this.Page.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20)); //only cache 20 minutes
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int count = file.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (count > 0)
                {
                    if (this.Page.Response.IsClientConnected)
                    {
                        this.Page.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                        count = file.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        count = -1;
                    }
                }
                this.Page.Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help me to resolve that problem.

Comment: Code looks ok (strange overriding of SP security, and unclear why would you try to stream down files by hand when they should be already accessible by url...). Do you have problem with getting the stream of the file on server or rendering in the browser (I don't expect ICO to render as IMG tag)

Answer (score 4):

You're not setting the [ContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.contenttype.aspx) property on the `Response`. Try setting the `ContentType` to `image/x-icon` (please note that the "correct" content type may be `image/vnd.microsoft.icon`, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444975/if-i-serve-favicon-ico-as-image-vnd-microsoft-icon-instead-of-image-x-icon-wi) seems to indicate you may run into problems with that type).

The code should look something like:

```
this.Page.Response.Clear();
this.Page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.Private);
this.Page.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20));
this.Page.Response.ContentType = "image/x-icon";
```